# Is there any way to run Virtualbox inside of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to automate some VM build processes. We are using Vagrant, with Virtualbox as our provider. We would like our VM builds to be conducted on EC2, but in order to build the image Virtualbox needs to start. Since Virtualbox cannot run on an EC2 machine, I'm wondering if there are any other AWS tools that can help with this.

Comment: if your intention is to build production VMs, you might be interested in Packer (also by HashiCorp) which is a unified image builder for Vagrant, Docker, EC2, etc https://www.packer.io/

Answer (score 2):

To build an EC2 AMI and launch some instances from it, you can use Boxfuse's generic Linux x64 support: https://boxfuse.com/docs/payloads/linux-x64

All you need to do is pass in a tar.gz file and the command to run and the rest is taken care of for you.

*Disclaimer: I am Boxfuse's founder and CEO*

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant has an "AWS" provider that lets you run Vagrant on EC2 from your local machine:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
$ vagrant up --provider=aws
```

If you've already provisioned a box with VirtualBox you'll need to remove it first with `vagrant destroy`

You also need to use an Amazon AMI instead of a regular box

```
vagrant box add aws-dummy https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box
```

in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.box = "aws-dummy"
require 'vagrant-aws'
config.vm.provider 'aws' do |aws, override|
  aws.access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  aws.secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  aws.keypair_name = 'default'
  aws.region = 'us-east-1'
  aws.ami = 'ami-e13739f6'
  aws.security_groups = ['default']
  override.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
  override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/ssh-keypair-file'
end
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/providers.html

http://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/09/15/using-vagrant-with-aws/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to run your code inside a container on AWS. But you can definitely use Docker [see here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). In fact, some AWS services use docker under the hood, e.g. Elastic Beanstalk.

I have also heard about [boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com/) service helping with deployment automation. And as far as I understand it creates images AWS can run directly. I never used this service myself though, so can't tell much.